# DAX - Last Value

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have this table

[image]

I would like to create measurement get the last traded value for each day. E.g.

[image]

How the DAX query should look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create two measures. One for the last time in each date and another to get the value for that date and time.

```
Last Time := 
CALCULATE(MAX([Time]),FILTER('Table',[Date]=MAX([Date])))
```

```
Last Traded Value =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Traded Value] ),
        FILTER ( 'Table', [Date] = MAX ( [Date] ) && [Last Time] = [Time] )
    )
```

Then add `Date` column to rows and `Last Time` and `Last Traded Value` measures to Values pane in a pivot table.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
DEFINE
VAR TableTMP =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 'Table', "DateTime", [Date] + [Time] )
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZE (
      NATURALINNERJOIN (
        TableTMP,
        SUMMARIZE  (
          GROUPBY ( TableTMP, [Date], "DateTime", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [DateTime] ) ),
          [DateTime]
        )
      ),
      [Date],
      [Time],
      [Traded Value]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [new window functions](https://pbidax.wordpress.com/2022/12/15/introducing-dax-window-functions-part-1/) in DAX, I think this can be simplified to

```
Last Traded Value =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table'[Traded Value] ),
    INDEX (
        1,
        ORDERBY ( 'Table'[Time], DESC ),
        PARTITIONBY ( 'Table'[Date] )
    )
)
```